# Непонятная потеря точности

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте,имеется следующий код:

```
double k = n * d;
int l = (int)Math.Truncate(k);
Text = k + "/" + l + "/" + (k - l);
```

В результате выполнения текст будет следующим `10.8/10/0.79999999`.
Не понимаю, с чего при вычитании из 10.8 десяти получается такой результат.Объясните,пожалуйста.Спасибо.

Comment: Понял,извините за повтор,спасибо